# Ubuntu at NVIDIA TV - CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version

Tags: ubuntu, cuda, driver, nvidia, android-tv

I wanted to use the NVIDIA TV as a device to test some CUDA codes on. I have tried to write Android + CUDA code but I have had issues related to "hard float" vs "soft float" arm/android/cuda libraries while linking.

So, I have installed Ubuntu Linux on the NVIDIA TV.

```
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~/devel/cuda/hello$ uname -a
Linux tegra-ubuntu 3.10.96 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Oct 13 05:30:55 EDT 2016 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

I have also pushed CUDA to the device using JetPack for JX1 device.

Even though I try to run an "Hello, World!" code, that only performs "cudaFree(0)", I do get the error of "CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version".

I have searched internet for CUDA / NVIDIA Drivers to install to this architecture, but I could not find any.

- Should I give up on this machine and buy a TX1 board?
- might it be possible to install NVIDIA CUDA/Graphics Drivers on it (how)
- would it require to rebuilt the kernel
- should I force my luck on developing Android+CUDA for this device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have given another try and saw that the sample CUDA applications are running fine at the Ubuntu Installed NVIDIA TV. So after installing Ubuntu on top of NVIDIA TV and then installing JetPack to it, it was possible to run CUDA applications.

I have figured out that the issue was that I was compiling the CUDA code against a different device runtime. When I compiled the .cu file like this, the application run successfully without any "insufficient" errors.

```
nvcc -arch=sm_52 example.cu -o example
```

As seen I have specified the architecture to match with NVIDIA TV and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Shield TV is not formally supported by Nvidia, as said by a moderator on the official devtalk forum :

> Ubuntu on Shield is not formally supported

See : [Cuda for Nvidia Shield TV](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/900358/jetson-tx1/cuda-for-nvidia-shield-tv/)

You should take a look at [NVIDIA CodeWorks for Android](https://developer.nvidia.com/codeworks-android)  which is their official native development tools package for Android :

> NVIDIA CodeWorks for Android 1R5 is a professional grade solution providing a comprehensive set of GPU and CPU tools with debugging, profiling and system trace capabilities and accompanying SDKs and libraries for Android development - not only on Tegra powered devices.

Full OS and platforms support is available on this same page.

Comment: You mean it will not be possible to install a driver to this device? I saw that people were able to run CUDA on the Ubuntu @NvidiaTv.

Comment: I have had issues while linking CUDA code along with Android / Arm libraries. libcudart.a has been built with "hard float", though the Android libraries requires "soft float". Do you know a version of CUDA libraries which are for aarch64/arm with "soft float" flag?

Comment: I don't know if it will be 100% impossible to install a regular driver on this device, but as it is not fully supported by Nvidia, I would myself consider it as a hack.
Unfortunately I have no experience about CUDA on Android, but if you have installations problem (instead of a programming one), it is off-topic for SO. You should try the Nvidia devtalk forum for more help.

Comment: I have given another try and saw that the example applications that are coming with CUDA are running fine on the device. I will understand the issue further and update here.